# Newton's Method derivative calculation

Tags: calculus, newton-raphson

I'm trying to reduce this form of Newtons Method for:

$f(x) = x^2 - a$, $f'(x) = 2x$

$$x_1 = x_0 - \frac {f(x_0)}{f'(x_0)}$$

to the form, which I am told is the correct expanded form:

$(x/2) + (a/(2x))$

I start:

$x_1 = x - (x^2 - a)/(2x)$

$x_1 = x - (x^2)/(2x) + a/(2x)$

$x_1 = 2x/2 - x/2 + a/2x$

$x_1 = x/2 + a/2x$

Unfortunately, I'm unable to see where the signs are incorrect for the last form.  Does anyone know where I went wrong in changing the form of this expression?  Thanks

UPDATE revised with solution

Comment: Why did $-\frac{x^2-a}{2x}$ become $-\frac{x}{2}-\frac{a}{2x}$?

Comment: @SangchulLee I added the second step for this

Comment: Let me reformulate my question: Writing $A=\frac{x^2}{2x}$ and $B={a}{2x}$, why did you get $-(A-B)=-A-B$ instead of $-A+B$?

Comment: I forgot to distribute the negative factor.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiply the first term in the Newton step by $\frac{2x_0}{2x_0}$ and combine the resulting fractions:
\begin{align*}
x_1 ={}& x_0 - \frac{x_0^2 - a}{2x_0} \\
={}& \frac{2x_0^2 - x_0^2 + a}{2x_0} \\
={}& \frac{x_0^2 + a}{2x_0} \\
={}& \frac{x_0}{2} + \frac{a}{2x_0}.
\end{align*}